# How do I extract value of a cell with the row and column numbers from a dataframe in R and then create a separate dataframe with the extracted values?

Tags: r

My data are in a dataframe like this:

| id | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | Cl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P_1 | 23 | 25 | 27 | 30 | 31 | 33 | 35 | 37 | 5 |
| P_2 | 20 | 27 | 25 | 30 | 28 | 32 | 26 | 26 | 3 |
| P_3 | 17 | 24 | 25 | 32 | 25 | 31 | 26 | 32 | 2 |
| P_4 | 14 | 24 | 25 | 33 | 22 | 30 | 22 | 38 | 6 |
| P_5 | 11 | 24 | 25 | 35 | 19 | 29 | 23 | 44 | 5 |
| P_6 | 8 | 24 | 25 | 30 | 16 | 28 | 20 | 50 | 6 |
| - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| P_10008 | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |

I have a dataframe with more than 10,000 rows and 14 columns (example attached in text using 8 columns). I indexed the row and column number from which I need to extract the value. The "Cl" column includes the column number (also id column) from which I would like to extract that value for each row. For example, from the first row I would like to extract the value “30” from the “D” column and also would like to keep the id column (P_1). Column “B” from the 2nd row with id P_2.

New dataset would be like,

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| P_1 | 30 |
| P_2 | 27 |
| P_3 | 17 |
| P_4 | 22 |
| P_5 | 35 |
| P_6 | 16 |
| - | - |
| - | - |
| P_10008 | - |

How do I write the code in a way in R that would allow me to extract the value of a cell with the row and column number for my whole dataset? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We cannot read data into R from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`, if that is not too large, or `dput(head(yourdata))` for the first few rows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to make a table, but the formatting is getting different after posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it as follows.  First, make the data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(id = c("p_1", "P_2", "P_3", "P_4", "P_5", "P_6", 
"P_7", "P_8", "P_9", "P_10"), A = c(23, 25, 23, 27, 30, 27, 23, 
25, 27, 30), B = c(25, 27, 25, 27, 30, 23, 24, 26, 28, 30), C = c(27, 
30, 27, 23, 25, 27, 30, 23, 16, 9), D = c(30, 23, 30, 13, 16, 
19, 22, 25, 28, 31), E = c(23, 34, 23, 25, 27, 30, 23, 24, 26, 
28)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

You can define the row index and column names you want to extract.  Below we are saying that take column "D" for row 1 and column "B" for row 2.

```r
row_index <- c(1,2)
col_values <- c("D", "B")
```

Next, you need to make a new data frame where the `id` value just comes from the `row_index` values of `id`.  The `value` column comes from the indicated column.  You could even have it save the column from which the number came as `column`:

```r
data.frame(id = dat$id[row_index], 
           value = dat[cbind(row_index, match(col_values, names(dat)))], 
           column = col_values)
#>    id value column
#> 1 p_1    30      D
#> 2 P_2    27      B
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>